# Running C# dll in browser for calculations only

Tags: dll, webassembly, blazor

I have C# code for fin. calculations, I'd like to run it in browser. I researched Blazor, but all examples I could find concentrated on ASP.NET, while I would like to download a .dll or .wasm file and execute it from my existing web application (written in Typescript). I'm looking for an example of this.

Comment: And to be clear, you don't want to (can't) use a Web API? Because that would be the normal way to use a C# lib from ts.

Comment: We already have api calls, now we are looking to improve our app. Getting rid of frequent roundtrips for recalculation is a good candidate - faster ui and less load on server. However, since this is enterprise calculations, I would only go for this if we can keep single codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to VibeeshanRC answer and Microsoft documentation, I adapted one of the Blazor examples by removing everything not relevant to manual invocation (UI related code). https://github.com/IKoshelev/BlazorExampleManualInvocation

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to run `WebAssembly` code inside a usual `JavaScript` or `Angular` page then you have to tinker the `bootstrapping js` files in the Blazer project, which is undocumented at the moment.

As of now, the easiest way is to create a simple Blazer project, Load that inside an `iFrame`, pass your data need to be calculated using js to the app.

From the javascript inside your application, you can call the `WebAssembly` methods.

Your C# Code

```
[JSInvokable]
public string SayHello() => $"Hello, {Name}!";
```

Your JS Caller

```
sayHello: function (dotnetHelper) {
    return dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('SayHello')
      .then(r => console.log(r));
  }
```

Refer for more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0